# Parameter in a controller function returns undefined ReferenceError

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm going through [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-(spa)-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs) learning lab for AngularJS. I can get the example to work as-is (with a minor bug fix).

I'm also trying to learn some good coding practices concerning AngluarJS by referencing [this guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide). This has resulted in a js file that looks like this:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('QuizApp', []);

angular.module('QuizApp').controller('QuizCtrl', QuizController);

function QuizController($http) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.answer = answer();
    vm.answered = false;
    vm.correctAnswer = false;
    vm.nextQuestion = nextQuestion();
    vm.options = [];
    vm.sendAnswer = sendAnswer(option);
    vm.title = "loading question...";
    vm.working = false;

    function answer() {
        return vm.correctAnswer ? 'correct' : 'incorrect';
    }

    function nextQuestion() {
        vm.working = true;
        vm.answered = false;
        vm.title = "loading question...";
        vm.options = [];

        $http.get("/api/trivia")
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            vm.options = data.options;
            vm.title = data.title;
            vm.answered = false;
            vm.working = false;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            vm.title = "Oops... something went wrong.";
            vm.working = false;
        });
    }

    function sendAnswer(option) {
        vm.working = true;
        vm.answered = true;

        $http.post('/api/trivia', { 'questionId': option.questionId, 'optionId': option.id })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            vm.correctAnswer = (data === true);
            vm.working = false;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            vm.title = "Oops... something went wrong.";
            vm.working = false;
        });
    }
};
})();
```

However, this code is throwing the following error when the page loads.

> ReferenceError: 'option' is undefined
>      at QuizController (http://localhost:17640/Scripts/app/quiz-controller.js:16:9)
>      at invoke (http://localhost:17640/Scripts/angular.js:4473:7)
>      at Anonymous function (http://localhost:17640/Scripts/angular.js:9093:11)
>      at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:17640/Scripts/angular.js:8205:13)
>      at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:17640/Scripts/angular.js:7637:13)
>      at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:17640/Scripts/angular.js:7641:13)
>      at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:17640/Scripts/angular.js:7641:13)
>      at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:17640/Scripts/angular.js:7641:13)
>      at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:17640/Scripts/angular.js:7641:13)
>      at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:17640/Scripts/angular.js:7512:30)

For whatever reason, it appears to be attempting to execute `sendAnswer` immediately. Since it's failing, the javascript halts mid-way displaying the angular property name {{title}} on the page instead of rendering the question on the page. I've tried different ways of defining and calling `vm.sendAnswer` and `function sendAnswer`, without any luck.

For reference, here is the code to my view (note the ng-repeat on options - this view code works perfectly when following the lab exercise exactly):

```
<div id="bodyContainer" ng-app="QuizApp">
<section id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="flip-container text-center col-md-12" ng-controller="QuizCtrl" ng-init="nextQuestion()">
                <div class="back" ng-class="{flip: answered, correct: correctAnswer, incorrect:!correctAnswer}">
                    <p class="lead">{{answer()}}</p>
                    <p>
                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg next option" ng-click="nextQuestion()" ng-disabled="working">Next Question</button>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="front" ng-class="{flip: answered}">
                    <p class="lead">{{title}}</p>
                    <div class="row text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg option" ng-repeat="option in options" ng-click="sendAnswer(option)" ng-disabled="working">{{option.title}}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

How can I preserve my coding practice (essentially, avoid using `$scope` in this situation and declare all of my viewmodel properties at the top of the controller) yet get the function to operate properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this example working now.

For starters, the controller properties that are plugged into functions just need to reference the names of the functions.

```
vm.answer = answer;
vm.nextQuestion = nextQuestion;
vm.sendAnswer = sendAnswer;
```

Then we need an alias for our controller on our view so we can reference it more easily.

```
<div class="flip-container text-center col-md-12" ng-controller="QuizCtrl as quiz" ng-init="quiz.nextQuestion()">
    <div class="back" ng-class="{flip: quiz.answered, correct: quiz.correctAnswer, incorrect:!quiz.correctAnswer}">
        <p class="lead">{{quiz.answer()}}</p>
        <p>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg next option" ng-click="quiz.nextQuestion()" ng-disabled="quiz.working">Next Question</button>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="front" ng-class="{flip: quiz.answered}">
        <p class="lead">{{quiz.title}}</p>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg option" ng-repeat="option in quiz.options" ng-click="quiz.sendAnswer(option)" ng-disabled="quiz.working">{{option.title}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And that's pretty much it. Just clean up the property definitions in the angular controller and then utilize an alias for the controller on the view. Everything else is pretty much the same code as what's in the question.

Here's the complete code now. Angular controller:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('QuizApp', []);

angular.module('QuizApp').controller('QuizCtrl', QuizController);

function QuizController($http) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.answer = answer;
    vm.answered = false;
    vm.correctAnswer = false;
    vm.nextQuestion = nextQuestion;
    vm.options = [];
    vm.sendAnswer = sendAnswer;
    vm.title = "loading question...";
    vm.working = false;

    function answer() {
        return vm.correctAnswer ? 'correct' : 'incorrect';
    };

    function nextQuestion() {
        vm.working = true;
        vm.answered = false;
        vm.title = "loading question...";
        vm.options = [];

        $http.get("/api/trivia")
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            var answerOptions = data.options;

            while (answerOptions.length > 0){
                var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * answerOptions.length, 0);
                alert(random);

                vm.options.push(answerOptions[random]);
                answerOptions.splice(random, 1);
            }

            //vm.options = data.options;
            vm.title = data.title;
            vm.answered = false;
            vm.working = false;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            vm.title = "Oops... something went wrong.";
            vm.working = false;
        });
    };

    function sendAnswer(option)
    {
        vm.working = true;
        vm.answered = true;

        $http.post('/api/trivia', { 'questionId': option.questionId, 'optionId': option.id }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            vm.correctAnswer = (data === true);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            vm.title = "Oops... something went wrong";                
        });

        vm.working = false;
    }
};
})();
```

MVC Index view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Play";
}

<div id="bodyContainer" ng-app="QuizApp">
    <section id="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="flip-container text-center col-md-12" ng-controller="QuizCtrl as quiz" ng-init="quiz.nextQuestion()">
                    <div class="back" ng-class="{flip: quiz.answered, correct: quiz.correctAnswer, incorrect:!quiz.correctAnswer}">
                        <p class="lead">{{quiz.answer()}}</p>
                        <p>
                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg next option" ng-click="quiz.nextQuestion()" ng-disabled="quiz.working">Next Question</button>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="front" ng-class="{flip: quiz.answered}">
                        <p class="lead">{{quiz.title}}</p>
                        <div class="row text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg option" ng-repeat="option in quiz.options" ng-click="quiz.sendAnswer(option)" ng-disabled="quiz.working">{{option.title}}</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app/quiz-controller.js")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to send in 

`vm.options = [];
    vm.sendAnswer = sendAnswer(option);`

`vm.options` into the sendAnswer() function because `option` is not defined. you won't get an error if you enclose 'option' in a string and pass it into the function.But then you wouldn't be getting the object you want.
add this somewhere at the top `var option = {}`.

Comment: I was in a hurry to leave and didn't post my view. There's an ng-repeat in the view on `options` that breaks them into multiple `option`s. Then there's an ng-click for `sendAnswer(option)`.

Comment: take out `vm.sendAnswer` your function will still operate properly. Also you can't access the `option`s data out of it function `sendAnswer()` except you pass the success response into another function.

Comment: Define "still operate properly." While removing the vm.sendAnswer definition removes the error, I now have no content on the page.